# "Cannot GET /" with res.sendFile() in Express

Tags: express, render

I'm trying to render index.html with res.sendFile but I'm not quite clear in how the paths work. I keep getting **"*Cannot GET /*"** when running it. I got it working before but I moved files and folders and I'm not finding the way of succeeding this time.

**code in index.js:**

```
const options = {root: path.join(__dirname, "/screens/")};

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html',options);
});
```

**this is how files are arranged:** (the index.html I'm trying to render is the one inside the screen's folder)

[image]

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

What change do I need to make here to replicate what you are doing? **This works**:

My code:

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: path.join(__dirname, "/screens/")});
});
 
const httpServer = http.Server(app);

httpServer.listen(8888, function () {
    console.log('Express server listening to port ' + httpServer.address().port);
});
```

**screens/index.html**

```
Hi Pop, how are you?
```

The above runs perfectly

Comment: thanks! i'll try that. thanks for the advice, what else should I share?? I tried to share everything relevant to the matter but maybe I skipped something

Comment: updated answer above - a second time to make it similar to what you asked in your question.